# How to configure apache server or htaccess so /file/name loads file without needing .php or .html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server

I recently moved from a managed dedicated server to a cloud server. The old server would serve the following URL

```
domain.com/folder/fileName
```

and it would display the .html version or the .php version depending on which one was present in the /folder/. If both were present, it would serve the .html version.

The new server requires the .php or .html to server the page. Any suggestions on updating the server or htaccess or ini or anything to allow for this functionality on the new server?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have access to the old server to see what configuration was done there?    Research RewriteRule in .htaccess if you must figure it out alone.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```